# Show or hide HTML depending on value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC project which uses Thymeleaf for front-end data binding. I would like to show a success message when a user's name was is updated. Here is the update screen: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGBJN.jpg) . At the moment, the user is redirected to the login page but I would like to show a message when the name is updated and wait 5 seconds before he is redirected. Can I pass a boolean in the page's get method and set it to true when the post method is called?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/resetUserName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView displayResetUsernamePage(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user) {
    logger.info("Entered displayResetUsernamePage function");
    return modelAndView;
 }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/resetUserName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setNewUsername(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser) throws ServletException {
    logger.info("Entered setNewUsername function");
    User exists = userService.findUserByUserName(user.getUsername());
    if (exists == null) {
        User updatedUser = userService.updateUsername(currentUser.getUsername(), user);           

        logger.info("Username change successful: " + currentUser.getUsername() + " is now " + user.getUsername());

        emailService.sendEmailResetUsername(user, currentUser);

    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }        

    modelAndView.setViewName("login");
    httpServletRequest.logout();
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Here are the get and post methods, can I pass a boolean to the get method and set it to true in the post method? And then show it in Thymeleaf with th:if${resetSuccess} to show the html?

something like this:

```
<div th:if="${resetSuccess}">
    Username change successfull !
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to updated users information and waiting 5 seconds and redirected to login page.

This is sample code for you :

1. maybe users move your get method page.
2. using to call to your post method in ajax.
3. using to updated user information in your post method.
4. response using in ajax and show your success message and wait 5 seconds and redirect your login page.

**edit your post method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset/account/{idx}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String resetAccount(@PathVariable long idx, @RequestBody User user) {

    // select user by idx.

    // update old user by new user. 

    // need to handle return string message.
    return "success";
}
```

**ajax**

```
// you need user idx.
var userIdx = 32;

// make user JSON.
var user = {
    "name" : "username"
}

user = JSON.stringify(user);


$.ajax({
        url : "/reset/account" + userIdx,
        type : 'POST',
        data : user,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'text',
        success : function(response) {

            // updated user information.
            if ("success" == response) {

                // show success message box.

                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.href = "/your/login/page";
                }, 5000);

            } else {
                // handling false or fail.
            }
        },

        error : function(request, status, error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I've updated my original post with the get and post method. Using your example, I would have to set success in the post method ? And where would I be able to show a message before it is redirected to the login page?

Comment: @Audiosleef updated answer. try this. maybe it works